# TF400307: The download operation timed out after waiting 600 seconds for a response from the server

Tags: c#, tfs, nuget

Today suddenly we are getting the below error on TFS build for different files. In every tfs build attempt the file names are different.

```
TF400307: The download operation timed out after waiting 600 seconds for a response from the server.
```

Nothing has been change on the solution related to the project in which I am getting this error.
I am getting this in only one tfs build, other branches for the same source code are working fine.

Can anyone help on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your entire log here? There might be some clue in the logs.

Comment: What's the TFS version do you use? Can you access the specific branch which have problems?Just check if you can get the sources from the specific branch with running the command `tf get` on the agent machine manually. Doubt that it's an network congestion issue.

Comment: We are using Visual Studio Team Services. So it should be the latest tfs version on cloud. Also on the local machine i am using visual studio 2017.

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque Have you resolved the issue? If you can download the files with command `tf get`, then it should be cache or temporary network connection issue. So just try to enable the `clean` option in your build definition to clean source directory, then try it again.

Comment: @Andy, already tried the said option, but no luck with that. One option worked for me was cleaning the local TFS cache, but it works only for one time, so i am cleaning cache before every build. very painful at the minute.

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque Base on your comments above, you are using VSTS. So, just want to know that how did you build the project? build in VSTS with hosted agent or private agent or just map sources to local workspace and build with VS locally?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT: i have mapped source on local machine and it is working fine on local. whenever i am trying to checkin the code on tfs, gated build i failing with above error.

Answer (score 1):

It probably due to some Cache file on the client Machine.

Please let the users who experience the issue clean the cache file on their client machine. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache`.

There is a similar thread [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/46d59566-5a39-4dd2-bc46-d20fd1cc4697/tfs-get-operation-hangs-after-retrieving-last-file) on MSDN Forum to follow up.